# Validating email in the textbox using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 2 textboxes and a submit button in a form. One which takes First Name as input and other one as Email. I am trying to validate the form by using angularjs. For the first name field, I apply

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : creatProspectSubmit && prospectCreate.FirstName.$error.required }"
```

This works perfectly and it highlights the textbox when there is no name in it. Another validation which I have added in the textbox is

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" ng-model="FirstName" ng-required="true">
```

So when I click on submit, the textbox gets highlighted and the form does not gets submitted.

There is a different validation for email field.

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : creatProspectSubmit && prospectCreate.Email.$error.required || EmailValidate || prospectCreate.Email.$error.email}">
```

So this works good and it highlights the textbox if it satisfies the above condition. Other validation is

```
<input type="email" name="Email" ng-model="Email" ng-required="true">
```

The problem here is it highlights the textbox if the email address is wrong but when I click on submit it accepts the value maybe it is because ng-required = "true" is satisfied. How can I stop the form from submitting without writing any code in the submit button.

I tried adding the below code in the textbox but it disappears the textbox of Email.

```
ng-if = "creatProspectSubmit && prospectCreate.Email.$error.required || EmailValidate || prospectCreate.Email.$error.email"
```

I am struggling on this from 2 days. I do not want to write any code on submit button. All the validations should be done in the textbox itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing you can do is to disable the submit button using ng-disabled if your condition is not satisfied. You can add your condition to ng-disabled, which should return false/true, based on which it will enable/disable the submit button.

Comment: Plz provide a plunker if u can

Comment: @User nope..dont want to touch the submit button

Comment: @RonakShah.. Ok. Then can you plz provide a plunkr or fiddle..

Comment: I fazed a similar issue an resorted to using ng-pattern="regex_to_validate_email_input", this took care of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add boolean validation vars to your scope,
so that on your submit button you could add ng-disable='!input1valid || !input2valid'
this way you'll get more control on when to submit or not